# Reading constants from .ini file for Inno Setup compilation

Tags: inno-setup

I wrote an innosetup script in order to prepare an installer requiring a password.
In order to keep separated the password from the innosetup code, I prepared an .ini file from where innosetup should read the password. Both archives are in the same folder together with the application to compile.

---- inno.iss -----

```
#define MyPswd "install.ini"
..............

[Setup]
..............
;Password=test                                 <- this works
Password={ini:{#MyPswd},Settings,pswd|test}    <- this doesnt work
............
```

---- install.ini -----

```
[Settings]
pswd=test
```

During installation I get a password error when I enter "test". With the direct Password=test, it installs correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

InnoSetup Compiler 5.4.2(u)
win 7 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Password directive can not contain runtime constants and so the password is literally `{ini:{#MyPswd},Settings,pswd|test}`. If you want to include the password at compile time, you will need to use ISPP to read the ini file value and `{#emit}` it:

```
{#ReadIni(MyPswd, "Settings", "pswd", "test")}
```

(Untested but should work)